# What kinds of mulch are there?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I already know how to make:

- Surprise Mulch
- Rich Mulch
- Boost Mulch.

However I have heard that there is more kinds of mulch but I am unable to make them. I have tried various ones but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: You are missing only **Amaze Mulch**, which has the combined effects of the other Mulches. It can be made by mixing a Kee or Maranga Berry with two other Berries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only 4 kinds of mulch in Pokemon X and Y. These are as follows:

- Amaze Mulch - Made with Kee/Maranga Berry + two others
- Boost Mulch - Made with Two Berries of the same colour + another Berry
- Rich Mulch - Made with 3 Berries of varied colours
- Surprise Mulch - Made with Three Berries of the same colour

[Source](http://www.serebii.net/xy/berryfields.shtml)